# Переключение фильтра у текстуры в LibGdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, mipmaps

Есть текстура, на сцене она должна отрисовываться в двух вариантах одновременно: пиксельной (Без MipMap) и размытой.
Текстура:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("test.png"), true);
```

Фильтр меняю через

```
texture.setFilter(minFilter, magFilter);
```

при смене с пиксельного режима на сглаженный текстура почему-то остаётся пиксельной при отрисовке. Т.е. фильтр меняется только один раз, а дельше почему-то нет.

Код метода `render` где batch - SpriteBatch, camera - OrthographicCamera:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

batch.begin();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest,Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
batch.draw(texture, 0,0);
texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear,Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
batch.end();
```

В фильтрах разбираюсь плохо, может там другая комбинация фильтров нужна?
Как исправить?

Или придётся делать копию текстуры?

Answer (score 0):

Недавно попадался похожий вопрос на англоязычном сайте. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378791/libgdx-texture-filters-and-mipmap).

Там предлагалось использовать assets manager и параметры.

```
 TextureParameter param = new TextureParameter();
 param.genMipMaps = true; // enabling mipmaps

 manager.load("path/to/texfile.png", Texture.class, param);

 Texture tex = manager.get("path/to/texfile.png", Texture.class);
 tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMap, TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

Может поможет.

Comment: Значит так можно будет менять фильтр сколько угодно раз?